# Синтаксис объявления массива

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
public static void main(String args[]){}
```

Почему иногда пишут как в первой строке, а иногда как во второй?
В чем разница? Как правильно

Comment: Возможно, вы удивитесь, но вариант с `var-args` тоже работает) `public static void main(String... args) {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это разный синтаксис объявления массивов в Java. Этими двумя способами объявляются любые массивы, не только в функции `main`, например вот:

```
int[] a;
int a[];
```

Семантически обе записи абсолютно одинаковы, пишите как вам больше нравится, это не более, чем дело вкуса.

Я лично предпочитаю первую запись, сразу видно, что тип `String[]` -- массив строк. Вторая запись сделана по аналогии с языком C, от которого Java во многом унаследовала свой синтаксис.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае варианты равнозначны, но бывают случаи, когда нет. Например вот здесь:
int [] a, b, c;
int a[], b, c;
В первом случае объявляются 3 массива интов, а во-втором только один массив a и 2 переменных (не массива) int.

Comment: Хорошее уточнение. ИМХО еще один довод к тому, чтоб использовать синтаксис `Тип[] переменная`.

Answer (score 0):

Так сделано из соображений простого удобства для программиста.
В одних языках программирования принят синтаксис, как в первом случае, в других - как во втором.

Разработчики Java решили прогнуться под всех и включили в язык оба синтаксиса, чтоб голову меньше парить тому, кто пришел из других языков.
Оба варианта абсолютно равнозначны и правильны. Вы можете использовать любой, из личных предпочтений или даже мешать оба варианта через одно объявление массива, если вдруг стало скучно.